# Plugin org.antlr:antlr4-maven-plugin:4.10.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, antlr4

Im building an application that reads parses code from thats input from a front end written in JavaFX, which forces me to make the whole project modular. Unfortunately antlr doesnt seem to support this yet and I get the following error when compiling: `Plugin org.antlr:antlr4-maven-plugin:4.10.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved`
Im using different modules, with a main pom and one for each module

here's the main pom:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
    <artifactId>chips-distribution-game-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>The Chips Distribution Game</name>
    <description>Een management spel om inzicht te geven in de dynamiek van een logistieke distributieketen
    </description>

    <modules>
        <module>game-logic</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>agent</module>
        <module>network</module>
        <module>game-manager</module>
        <module>user-interface</module>
        <module>shared-dtos</module>
        <module>jacoco-aggregator</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
            ${project.basedir}/../jacoco-aggregator/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml
        </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <sonar.junit.reportPaths>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            agent/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/agent/App.java,
            game-logic/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/gamelogic/App.java,
            game-manager/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/gamemanager/App.java,
            network/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/network/App.java,
            persistence/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/persistence/App.java,
            shared-dtos/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/shareddtos/**,
            user-interface/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/userinterface/**
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>

        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <skipUnitTests>${skipTests}</skipUnitTests>
        <skipIntegrationTests>${skipTests}</skipIntegrationTests>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- We need a constant finalName for use in the Dockerfile -->
        <profile>
            <id>shade</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>shade</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.CR1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
            <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>shade</id>
                            <!-- Only needed for manual integration testing -->
                            <phase>none</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipIntegrationTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.8</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                            <maximum>0</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

and here's the pom for the module that fails on compilation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>chips-distribution-game-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>agent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <name>chips-distribution-game-agent-component</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven-antlr4</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/152/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven-antlr4</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/152/packages/maven</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared-dtos</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.10.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>antlr</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.App</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.parser.AgentParser</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.parser.AgentParser.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.ast.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.demo.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.datastructures.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>shade</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here is the module-info for the failing component

```java
module nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent {
    requires org.antlr.antlr4.runtime;

    requires nl.han.aim.asd.game.persistence;
    requires nl.han.aim.asd.game.shareddtos;

    exports nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no 4.10.2 version (at this time), try [4.10.1](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.10.1/jar) instead.

### EDIT

I tried with the following (I commented out some dependencies, but left the ANTLR dependencies):

##### parent

```xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
    <artifactId>chips-distribution-game-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>The Chips Distribution Game</name>
    <description>Een management spel om inzicht te geven in de dynamiek van een logistieke distributieketen
    </description>

    <modules>
        <module>game-logic</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>agent</module>
        <module>network</module>
        <module>game-manager</module>
        <module>user-interface</module>
        <module>shared-dtos</module>
        <module>jacoco-aggregator</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
            ${project.basedir}/../jacoco-aggregator/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml
        </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <sonar.junit.reportPaths>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportPaths>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            agent/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/agent/App.java,
            game-logic/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/gamelogic/App.java,
            game-manager/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/gamemanager/App.java,
            network/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/network/App.java,
            persistence/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/persistence/App.java,
            shared-dtos/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/shareddtos/**,
            user-interface/src/main/java/nl/han/aim/asd/game/userinterface/**
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>

        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <skipUnitTests>${skipTests}</skipUnitTests>
        <skipIntegrationTests>${skipTests}</skipIntegrationTests>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/148/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- We need a constant finalName for use in the Dockerfile -->
        <profile>
            <id>shade</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>shade</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.CR1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
            <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>shade</id>
                            <!-- Only needed for manual integration testing -->
                            <phase>none</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipIntegrationTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>CLASS</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.8</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                            <maximum>0</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

##### pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>chips-distribution-game-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <relativePath>parent.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>agent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <name>chips-distribution-game-agent-component</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven-antlr4</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/152/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven-antlr4</id>
            <url>http://gitlab.devops.aimsites.nl/api/v4/projects/152/packages/maven</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.han.aim.asd.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared-dtos</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>antlr</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.App</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.parser.AgentParser</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.parser.AgentParser.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.ast.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.demo.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.datastructures.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>shade</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>nl.han.aim.asd.game.agent.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And a `mvn clean` resulted in:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< nl.han.aim.asd.game:agent >----------------------
[INFO] Building chips-distribution-game-agent-component 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent (default) @ agent ---

...

[INFO] --- antlr4-maven-plugin:4.10.1:antlr4 (antlr) @ agent ---
[INFO] No ANTLR 4 grammars to compile in /home/bart/Temp/pom-tets/src/main/antlr4
[INFO] 

...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.631 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-12T10:40:36+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: 4.10.1 doesnt seem to work either but thx anyway

Comment: OK, for the record, in case anyone stumbles upon this question, 4.10.1 works fine in my `pom.xml`, but 4.10.2 does not (which is no surprise given it does not exist at this date in Maven Central)

Comment: @arrayZero did you try 4.10.1 for both dependencies: `antlr4-runtime` and `antlr4-maven-plugin`? And what error do you get when you try with 4.10.1? ("doesn't work" can mean an awful lot...)

Comment: @arrayZero check my EDIT, it works on my machine. I think you accidentally only updated a single 4.10.2.

Answer (score -2):

Your main problem is that your statement "[JavaFX] forces me to make the whole project modular" is simply wrong. You can easily write a JavaFX application in a non-modular fashion. I am doing that for years.

Comment: The statement may be wrong, but that is not the main problem. The main problem is the fact that there is no ANTLR (runtime) version 4.10.2